# Double enter replace with space using regular expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

My condition is like this:

```
1:3 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.</p>

<p>And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.
```

I want to merge this 2 lines to one with space using regular expression in C#

I used

```
 var p = Regex.Match(line, @”</p>\n\n<p>[A-z]“);
 if (p.Success)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(p.Value);
 }
```

Comment: what is the outcome? And what is going wrong? I think there is something as [Regex.Replace()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of Regex. Try

```
line = line.Replace("\n\n", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Regex.Replace`:

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"</p>\n\n<p>", " ");
```

However, an easier method would be:

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"(</?p>|\s)+", " ");
```

This is also more robust against how many line breaks are in that text or what kind.

Comment: I tried this expression also but it is not working. It is not finding the expression itself.

Comment: This is my text:1:3 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.</p>^p
^p
<p>And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.

I want to merg these 2 lines by removing </p> and <p>

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need regular expression? You can simply use `s = s.Replace("\n\n", " ");`